# Maya Calendar right window remains empty

Tags: calendar

I'm using Loki, Maya Calendar.

On the right window (with the Date of the day chosen in the month-view) should appear a list with the entries of that specific day, but it doesen't. The right window remains empty, what ever I choose in the month-view. Is there any trick, that I didn't understand yet or is it a bug?

Cheerio

Carlos

Answer (score 1):

No that is most definitely a bug, you could try running the latest master as there have been quite a lot of fixes recently about events not showing correctly in Calendar, however that would require building it, if not wait for the next release of Calendar. Sorry for the bad news.